# How to send image link from Laravel storage to frontend(angular). All work property except image

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel

```
  public function index(){
        $data = HeaderSlider::all();
        return $data;
    }

  <ul *ngFor="let item of data">
    <img [src]="item.image"  />
  </ul>
```

How to send (Laravel) image as link to frontend(angular)
Where I store my image which sending like a response ? I try with storage in laravel but without success? I only want send link from server to frontend angular and in Angular bind src and print image. All my data from index function laravel come to frontend and all work property except image link ? Which folder in laravel is main for storage image?  I try to search on google answer but I find only for request input type i don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

```
i'm also working on angular with laravel , best approach to is to concatenate full url in laravel query with image , like , 
Website Url where you will put your laravel api address
-------------------------------------------------------

HeaderSlider::CrossJoin('websiteurl')->select(DB::raw('CONCAT("websiteurl.base_url , headerslider.image") as image'))->get()
```

Comment: I don't understand
This is little complicate

Comment: website Url is another table , where you will put full url , like www.example.com/api , your image path would be storage/image/path , now you have to conacatenate www.example.com/storage/image/path

Answer (score 1):

1. create column as

   if (!Schema::hasTable('file_attachment')) {

   ```
      Schema::create('file_attachment', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->increments('FileAttachmentID');
              **$table->string('FileType')->nullable();
              $table->string('FilePath')->nullable();
              $table->integer('FileSourceID')->nullable();
              $table->integer('SourceID')->nullable();**
              //$table->dateTime('CreatedOn')->nullable();
              $table->integer('CreatedBy')->nullable();
              //$table->dateTime('ModifiedOn')->nullable();
              $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
              $table->timestamps();
     });
   ```

   }

in response send filepath in json.

Answer (score 1):

if you are storing the image in laravel public directory.
if the image available in public/images/beautifulNature.jpg. Then send **/images/beautifulNature.jpg** as the URL to the frontend and use in your html component something like this.

```
<img src="{{url('/images/beautifulNature.jpg')}}" alt="Image"/>
```